# How can I separate an image file by color region into multiple image files?

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

Take this image of a circle and a square on a transparent background (png).

[image]

I want to split this image by region. The regions are defined by connected color. I have a circle region. And a square region.

The output would be, one image file with the circle on it

[image]

and a second image file with the square on it.

[image]

Can ImageMagick do this? Can another tool do this? How can I do this?

Comment: See connected components processing

Comment: Or floodfill the region you don't want so it merges into the background.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to do that in ImageMagick. I note that your posted image has a white background, not a transparent one. However, I have changed the white to transparent. I first get the bounding boxes of the objects using connected components. Then I loop over each bounding box and crop it out and put it back into a transparent image using the virtual canvas information stored in the cropped image.

Input:

[image]

```
bboxArr=(`convert circle_rectangle_transp.png -type bilevel \
-define connected-components:verbose=true \
-define connected-components:exclude-header=true \
-define connected-components:mean-color=true \
-connected-components 8 null: | grep "gray(0)" | awk '{print $2}'`)

echo "${bboxArr[*]}"

i=0
for bbox in ${bboxArr[*]}; do
echo $bbox
convert circle_rectangle_transp.png -crop "$bbox" -background none -flatten  circle_rectangle_transp_$i.png
i=$((i+1))
done
```

[image]

[image]